# How to display a calculation result on a New view/page in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-template

I am new in Angular. I'm trying create my first simple Angular calculator app, everything fine. Now I want to do this : When I perform a calculation, the result of that calculation will be displayed in another view/page. Can you show me some ways or keywords for this ?

**My app**:
[image]

**Code:**

calculator.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">CALCULATOR</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group value">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Value 1:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10 input-1">
                        <input [(ngModel)]='number1' class="form-control inp" type="number" name="num1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Value 2:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10 input-2">
                        <input [(ngModel)]='number2' class="form-control inp" type="number" name="num2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <br>
                <button class="butt" (click)='sum()'> + </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="butt" (click)='diff()'> - </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="butt" (click)='mult()'> x </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="butt" (click)='divi()'> / </button>
                <br><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="result">
                <h3 class="">Result: {{result}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

calculator.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  public number1: number;
  public number2: number;
  public result: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  sum() {
    this.result = this.number1 + this.number2;
  }

  diff() {
    this.result = this.number1 - this.number2;
  }

  mult() {
    this.result = this.number1 * this.number2;
  }

  divi() {
    this.result = this.number1 / this.number2;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CalculatorComponent, call this function after each calculation in order to set the result of calculation:

```
setTotal(){
  localStorage.setItem('total', this.result);
}
```

Now trigger new page to be open..

Then, go to new page's `ts` file, and retrieve the result from localStorage:

```
this.total = localStorage.getItem('total');
```

Now in html file belonging to new page, display the result:

```
{{ total }}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I call that function after each calculation, an error occurs ```Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string```. Why did it happen ?

Answer (score 1):

use angular routing for display data one page to another page
 this.router.navigate(['your page name'], { state: value })

state: value means you have to pass value of your result

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do that is creating a service component, that will be used to set and read data (this is the order you need in your example, but could be any). Please, note you should know how to subscribe to this service component, so i recommend you to read about subscribers and observables before.

Using angular routes or localStorage is not secure, so i wouldn't do that. The major rason is this could be easily modified by end-users

Comment: If possible, please answer to the point. Please add code snippet of that worked for u.